# Navigating across multiple presentations - Can it be implemented using javascript?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cookies, session-cookies

I have two presentations:

> Presentation A & B
>
> I started with Presentation A, went till slide 3 and navigated to Presentation B, went through some of the slides and returned back to Presentation A.

Here I should land on slide 3 where I left earlier?

Can it be done through Javascript using cookies? If so, what algorithm should be used?

Comment: Feel free to mark a response as accepted. Help keep the site clean by not leaving questions open.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done using javascript. As for the algorithm:

1. When a presentation is loaded, check for your cookie.
2. If it exists, jump to the slide number saved.
3. If it does not exist, create the cookie with value 1 (referring to first slide).

You should use a cookie name which would be specific to the presentation, perhaps something like `sitename_presentation_[presentation_id]`
That's pretty much it. You can find more information about setting and reading cookies in javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).